# Detección secuencia de símbolos de puntuación

Tags: python-3.x, string, regex

Quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de utilizar una expresión regular en Python 3 para detectar una secuencia de 5 símbolos de puntuación que pueden contener o '!' o '.' (!!!!!/..... o cualquier combinación de éstos ..!!! / .!.!. / etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si los signos de puntuación son solo punto o admiración, la expresión regular sería:

```
r"[\.!]{5}"
```

Los corchetes indican un conjunto del cual elegir un elemento. En este caso los elementos son el punto (que debe ponerse con un `\` delante, pues el punto tiene significado especial en una regex) o la admiración. Fuera de los corchetes aparece `{5}` que significa que el elemento anterior debe aparecer 5 veces. Pero el elemento anterior es el conjunto, del cual se puede elegir un elemento diferente cada vez. Así que esto cubre tus necesidades.

**Nota** La `r""` es una forma de crear en python cadenas "raw", que puedan contener el carácter `\` sin que python lo trate de forma especial.

**Nota2** Esta expresión regular encajaría también si hay más de 5 signos seguidos, como en "!!!...". Si quieres evitar un caso así, deja un comentario.

**Ejemplo de código completo**

```
import re

casos = [ "Este no!!", "Este si!!!!!", "Vale!.!.!", "Debería pasar este?!!!...", "Este ....! si"]

r = r"[\.!]{5}"

for caso in casos:
  if re.findall(r, caso):
    print("OK--->", caso)
  else:
    print("no--->", caso)
```

Salida:

```
no---> Este no!!
OK---> Este si!!!!!
OK---> Vale!.!.!
OK---> Debería pasar este?!!!...
OK---> Este ....! si
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, ha funcionado. En mi caso no importaría que detecte más ya que en el texto que estoy tratando solo se tienen la posibilidad de encontrar 5 signos seguidos.

Comment: Si te ha solucionado el problema, puedes agradecerselo aceptando la respuesta (pulsando el tick verde)